# When do i have to add a null terminator?

Tags: c

I know that i C , you always have to add a null terminator `\0`  so that the processor knows when a word was ended .

But i get hard time to understand when you have to do it . so for example this code works for me  without it :

```
  char connectcmd[50]={0};
  sprintf(connectcmd,"AT+CWJAP=\"%s\",\"%s\"",MYSSID,MYPASS);
```

How is that possible ?
When do you really have to add them ?

Comment: (Almost) all string related functions do this **automatically**. ("Almost", because of `strncpy`. As this function is the source of much misunderstanding, frustration & gnashing of teeth, you're better off pretending it does not exist until you know enough to use it properly.)

Comment: @Jongware thanks !  i actually use it a lot ! and it caused me pain :) so if i have a string that is already null terminated for some reason , then i do the strncpy , it wouldn't be null terminated anymore ??

Comment: It depends. Why state that strings may be "null terminated for some reason"? If they are not to begin with, *all* string operations are off limit! As I said, forget this function even exist until you comprehend the basic string operations in full.

Comment: so should i replace it with sprintf ?

Comment: ... there *is* only a `sprintf` in this code. You are talking about other code than in your question. If you are having problems with your current  `strncpy` code, please post that as another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sprintf` writes a null terminated string `connectcmd`, regardless of its initial contents. This works as long as you don't try to write beyond the bounds of the buffer.

On top of that, when you say this:

```
char connectcmd[50]={0};
```

you initialize all 50 elements of `connectcmd` to zero, which is the value of the null-terminator `\0`. So it would be null-terminated even if you wrote characters to it manually, as long as you write less than `50` non-null characters.

Comment: so if i fill the array with lets say 30 characters , then the null termination is in the index 49 , so should i get many spaces ??

Comment: @Curnelious No, the characters from index 30 to index 49 are null terminators, so the string terminates after index 29. If you call `strlen` on it, you get 30.

Comment: but it is full of zeros, but zeros are not \0 ? (sorry if its a stupid question)

Comment: @Curnelious They are, but the null termination is the first zero.

Comment: The initial value of `connectcmd` is irrelevant. You overwrite it with a new string - and `sprintf` does the Right Thing on its own, zero-terminating it.

Comment: oh ok, so this comment is different from your answer, you wrote in the answer that its already full of null terminators ,and then i fill the first 10/20 index with some characters. So its the sprint that adds it ?

Comment: @Curnelious Yes , `sprintf` will add it no matter what .

Comment: @Curnelious I changed the emphasis of the answer. `sprintf` takes care of the null-termination.

Comment: thanks. but again ,your answer is a little bit different :) because if i wouldn't do the sprint , according to your answer , any value added to it will be there at the start, and the rest of it is already null terminated ..

Answer (score 5):

`sprintf` always terminates it with `null character` , so no need to mannually add it.

From C99 standard -

> 7.21.6.6 The sprintf function
>
> [...]A null character is written at the end of the characters written; it is not counted as part of the returned value. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

> for example this code works for me without it

It does not (work *without* it).

The string literal `"AT+CWJAP=\"%s\",\"%s\""` has a null terminator at the end (like every string literal). `sprintf` copies that null terminator to `connectcmd` as well.

> When do you really have to add them ?

When you're manually building a string, or using a library function whose documentation explicitly states that it isn't going to add a terminating null.